# Is there a way to select normalized data back into one result set

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables.  Foo, Attrib, FooAttrib.  Where FooAttrib is the bridge between foo and attrib.  As you can see there are many foo's and many attribs in the table.

```
 Foo                 FooAttri                          Attrib
 ------------      -----------------------------     --------------
| id |  Name |    | fooId   |  attribId | value |   | id | Descrip |
|----|-------|    |---------|-----------|-------|   |----|---------|  
|  1 |  Sam  |    |  1      |     1     | red   |   |  1 | Color   |
|  2 |  Bill |    |  1      |     2     | Grape |   |  2 | Flavor  |
|  3 |  Ted  |    |  2      |     1     | Blue  |   |  3 | Weight  |
 ------------     |  3      |     3     |  10   |    --------------
                  |  1      |     3     |   5   |
                  |  2      |     3     |   1   |
                   -----------------------------
```

I know how to get the following:

```
fooId   Name     Attrib     Value
1       Sam      Color      red     
1       Sam      Flavor     Grape    
1       Sam      Weight     5
2       Bill     Color      Blue
2       Bill     Weight     1
3       Ted      Weight     10
```

But what I want to know is; Is it possible to build a select statement so that I get foo and attrib data all returned in one result set that looks like the following?

```
fooId   Name     Color   Flavor   Weight
1       Sam      red     Grape    5
2       Bill     Blue             1
3       Ted                       10
```

Comment: What you have there is basic EAV model (Entity-Attribute-Value) which is column-oriented modelling and the process of transfornign from column > row model is called pivoting. Googling for pivoting or searching this site for the same term should give you an insight on how to do it, however the best approach is to do it in the application (php, c, python or whatever you use) than to try to do it in MySQL.

Comment: @N.B.  Thank you for the response, the terminology alone is very helpful.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: You do undestand that an EAV data model is a very difficult to query and veryu  bad for performance. It is the worst possible design for most things in a relational database and is a SQL antipattern. If you truly need EAV, I'd suggest a nosql database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it if you know the total possible arguments you want at select time:

```
select f.id, f.name, fa_color.value as color, , fa_flavor.value as flavor
from foo f
join fooattri fa_color on f.id = fa_color.fooid and fa_color.attribid = 1
join fooattri fa_flavor on f.id = fa_flavor.fooid and fa_flavor.attribid = 2
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...what if I don't know the number of attribs I'm going to have?  Or another way to ask this would be what if the list of attribs can change (have more added to it)?

Comment: Problem in pivoting is that you have to know max. number of attributes so you know how many times you need to self-join the table. Otherwise you cannot get the regular layout out. That's why people usually do this pivoting in app languages since it's easier and faster. If you intend to query your EAV dataset by creating pivoted table or a view - don't bother, it will be terribly, terribly slow.

Comment: With EAV tables you have to knwo in advance the number of attributes becasue youhave to join to the table once for each attricute. This is one of the reasons why this design is a very poor idea.

Comment: Yeah, I provide this answer as a possible 'solution'.  But it can only work in a limited subset of situations.

Comment: @kasdega Another possible 'addition' to this 'solution' would be to query the possible attributes first then build a dynamic select statement based on them.  But going 'vertical' is _much_ better.

Comment: Yep that's what I may have to do.  Either way this answer gets me what I need at the moment so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this technique usually works for me:

```
SELECT fo.id, fo.name, 
  (SELECT fooattri.value 
  FROM fooattri 
    INNER JOIN attrib ON attrib.id = fooattri.attribid 
  WHERE attrib.descrip = 'Color' 
    AND fooattri.fooid = fo.id) AS Color, 
  (SELECT fooattri.value 
  FROM fooattri 
    INNER JOIN attrib ON attrib.id = fooattri.attribid 
  WHERE attrib.descrip = 'Flavor' 
    AND fooattri.fooid = fo.id) AS Flavor, 
  (SELECT fooattri.value 
  FROM fooattri 
    INNER JOIN attrib ON attrib.id = fooattri.attribid 
  WHERE attrib.descrip = 'Weight' 
    AND fooattri.fooid = fo.id) AS Weight 
FROM foo fo
```